# If $y=\frac{\sin kx}{1+\cos kx }$ where $k$ is a positive integer, show that $\sin kx\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=k^2y^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $$y=\frac{\sin kx}{1+\cos kx }$$ where $k$ is a positive integer, show that $$\sin kx\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=k^2y^2$$

My attempt:

$$y+y\cos kx=\sin kx$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+(\frac{dy}{dx}\cos kx -yk\sin(kx))=k\cos(kx)$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\cos(kx)-k\frac{dy}{dx}\sin(kx)-yk^2\cos(kx)+\frac{dy}{dx}k\sin(kx)=-k^2\sin(kx)$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}(1+\cos(kx))=-k^2\sin(kx)+yk^2\cos(kx)$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{yk^2\cos(kx)-k^2\sin(kx)}{1+\cos(kx)}$$

$$\sin(kx)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\sin^2kx}{1+cos(kx)}*\frac{k^2\cos(kx)}{1+\cos(kx)}-\frac{k^2\sin^2(kx)}{1+cos(kx)}$$

Not sure where I did wrong that I cant get $k^2y^2$.

Comment: I think you have a sign error on line 3. The last expression on the LHS should be a subtraction and not an addition.

Comment: I guess Line 3 should be $-\dfrac{dy}{dx}k\sin(kx)$.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a sign error early on. Upon fixing that, you might get something correct that seems wrong until you apply a half angle identity. You might use it at the end of your proof, but starting things off with the substitution saves time.

$y=\frac{\sin kx}{1+ \cos kx}=\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos kx}}{\sqrt{1+\cos kx}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1+\cos kx}}{\sqrt{1+\cos kx}}=\tan (kx/2)$

Prove $\sin kx \cdot y''=k^2y^2$

$dy/dx=(k/2)\sec^2(kx/2)$

$d^2y/dx^2=(k^2/4)\cdot 2 \cdot \sec^2{(kx/2)}\tan(kx/2)=(k^2/2)\sec^2{(kx/2)}\tan(kx/2)$

$\sin (kx) y'' =2\sin(kx/2)\cos (kx/2) (k^2/2)\sec^2(kx/2)\tan(kx/2)=k^2\tan^2(kx/2)=k^2y^2$

Comment: Without resorting to square roots: $\sin(kx)=2\sin(kx/2)\cos(kx/2)$ (which you use again later) and $1 + \cos(kx)=2\cos^2(kx/2)$.